# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar en Spring Boot el siguiente mensaje: Request method 'POST' not supported?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot

Saludos Comunidad me genera el siguiente mensaje de salida cuando quiero actualizar o crear un registro:

```
 Request method 'POST' not supported;
 Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported.
```

A continuación dejo el código.

En el controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/direccion")
@Controller
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true,securedEnabled = true, 
jsr250Enabled = true)
public class DireccionController {

private DireccionService direccionService;

private UsuarioService usuarioService;


public DireccionController(DireccionService direccionService,UsuarioService usuarioService) {

    this.direccionService = direccionService;
    this.usuarioService=usuarioService;
}



@GetMapping("/actualizar/{id}")
public String actualizarDireccion(@PathVariable Long id,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("direccion",direccionService.getDireccion(id));
    model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
    return "direccion/lista";
}


@GetMapping("/lista")
public String direccionLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
    model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
    return "direccion/lista";

}

@GetMapping("/lista/{id}")
public Optional<Direccion> getDireccion(@PathVariable Long id){
    return direccionService.getDireccion(id);

}
@RequestMapping(value="/agregar",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String direccionForm(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("direccion",new Direccion());
    model.addAttribute("usuarios", usuarioService.usuarioLista());
    return "direccion/lista";
}

@PostMapping("/agregar")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('admin')")
public String agregarDireccion(@ModelAttribute("direccion") Direccion direccion,Model model,BindingResult bindingResult)throws IOException {



    String mensaje="";
    if(direccion.getId()==null ){
        mensaje="agregado";
    } 
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

    }

    else{
        mensaje="actualizado";
    }

    model.addAttribute("mensaje", direccionService.agregarDireccion(direccion).getUsuario().getUsuarioNombre()+"direccion"+mensaje+"direccion agregado...");
    return "redirect:/direccion/lista";

}

@GetMapping("/eliminar/{id}")
public String eliminarDireccion(@PathVariable  Long id,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("mensaje",direccionService.eliminarDireccion(id));
    return "redirect:/medida/lista";

}   
}
```

En el jsp.

```
<div class="container">
<br>
     <button  class="btn btn-primary nBtn" >Nuevo</button>
      <br>
      <br>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-block">

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
            <th>Distrito</th>
            <th>Pais</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Actualizar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>   
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${direcciones}" var="direccion">
            <tr>
                <td>${direccion.id}</td>
                <td>${direccion.ciudad}</td>
                <td>${direccion.distrito}</td>
                <td>${direccion.pais}</td>
                <td>${direccion.usuario.usuarioNombre}</td>
                <td><a href="${path}/direccion/actualizar/${direccion.id}" class="btn btn-primary eBtn">Actualizar</a></td>
                <td><a href="${path}/direccion/eliminar/${direccion.id}"  class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>

    </tbody>



</table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="myForm">

<form:form  action="${path}/direccion/lista" method="post"  modelAttribute="<direcciones>,<usuarios>" >

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" 
    tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar o Guardar</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="form-group">
                <label for="id" class="col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value=""/>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pais" class="col-form-label">Pais:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" value=""/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ciudad" class="col-form-label">Ciudad:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" name="ciudad"  value=""/>
              </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="distrito" class="col-form-label">Distrito:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distrito" name="distrito" value=""/>
              </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="usuario" class="col-form-label">Usuario:</label>

                    <select name="usuario.id" id="usuario" required>
                        <c:forEach items="${usuarios}" var="usuario" >

                            <option value="${usuario.id}">${usuario.usuarioNombre}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>   
                </div>



         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="guardar"/>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    </form:form>
  </div>
```

En el JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.nBtn, .table .eBtn').on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var text=$(this).text();

    if(text=='Actualizar' ){ 


    $.get(href,function(direccion,usuario,status){
        $('.myForm #id').val(direccion.id);
        $('.myForm #ciudad').val(direccion.ciudad);
        $('.myForm #distrito').val(direccion.distrito);
        $('.myForm #pais').val(direccion.ciudad);
        $('.myForm #nombre').val(usuario,nombre);
    });

    $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();

}else{

    $('.myForm #id').val('');
    $('.myForm #ciudad').val('');
    $('.myForm #distrito').val('');
    $('.myForm #pais').val('');
    $('.myForm #usuario').val('');

    $('.myForm #exampleModal').modal();
}

});
});
```

Comment: Prueba de añadir en @RequestMapping el metodo que vas a utilizar. Osea method = RequestMethod.POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas mandando esto desde tu form:

```
<form:form  action="${path}/direccion/lista" method="post"  modelAttribute="<direcciones>,<usuarios>" >
```

Pero solo tienes un `@GetMapping("/lista")`:

```
@GetMapping("/lista")
public String direccionLista(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("direcciones",direccionService.direccionLista());
    model.addAttribute("usuarios",usuarioService.usuarioLista());
    return "direccion/lista";

}
```

Necesitas un `@PostMapping("/lista")`. El `Error 500` es un error interno y la traza que colocas:

> Request method 'POST' not supported; Resolved exception caused by
>   Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'POST' not supported.

...significa que spring esta buscando un método que resuelva `/direccion/lista` por medio de `POST` pero no lo hay. Solo hay una coincidencia con `GET`...  aunque eso no le interesa al descorazonado de spring xS.

Comment: Gracias es cierto pero ahora en el controller en agregarDireccion cambie a postMapping("/lista")  ahora lo malo cuando quiero actualizar   me crea otro registro pero quiero solo actualizar

Comment: Puedes tener dos operaciones con el mismo request, uno con `@PostMapping('/lista')` y otro con `@GetMapping('/lista')`.